# Ajax запрос на другой домен

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

Всем привет, появился такой вопрос, возможно ли посылать Ajax запрос на сторонний домен c http в то время как твой домен на https?

Пользуюсь сервисом проверки БИК, но он не работает с https, просто виснет и не подает признаков жизни. 
Если посылать запрос на него когда твой сайт находится на http, то все отлично работает, но если сайт перевести на https, то все, сервис перестает отвечать. Насколько я понял это потому что Ajax автоматически переводит url с http на https.

Comment: _возможно ли посылать Ajax запрос на сторонний домен c http в то время как твой домен на https_ - нет, браузеры не пропускают такие запросы

Comment: @Grundy печально. Благодарю.

Comment: По идее есть один обход, но черезпопуногузадерищенский) Называется он - расширение для браузеров.... А так - `curl` пэхэпэшный кто-то юзает

Comment: JSONP должен работать. Хотя браузеры будут ругаться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а попробуйте использовать php и curl, а уже с файлом php держите связь по ajax, например массивы можете в json получать и обрабатывать. В интернете есть статьи по работе curl с https.

*сurl в php - это библиотека которая дает возможность соединяться с серверами различных типов и по разным протоколам. libcurl в настоящее время поддерживает протоколы http, https, ftp, gopher, telnet, dict, file и ldap. Её удобно использовать например тогда, когда вам нужно использовать API запросы. Её описание довольно достаточно можно найти на php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php , но можно подсмотреть примеры использования и на stackoverflow*

Comment: добавьте описание, что такое _curl_

Comment: А вот такой вариант почему то не обдумывал.. в целом так и сделаю. Благодарю.